# Exception regarding UITable view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.3, uistoryboard

I'm new to Objective C and iOS. I have embedded a Navigation controller on a View Controller to the storyboard. Then I've added another view controller to the storyboard, which is the root view controller. It has a button that connects to another view controller that has a table view added to it. When I run the build, I'm getting the following exception : 'NSInvalidArgumentException' reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x686d160'. Here's the code in the implementation file (only the relaevant methods) Please tell me if I need to provide any more code:

```
     (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
    return [contacts count];
   }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:      (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is contacts array has values?

Comment: it clearly shows that your `contacts` array has some invalid values like empty or null. So make sure that it is not null and have some value in it.

Comment: You can send messages to a nil object, but you can't send messages to a deallocated object.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's possible to get that error. It's saying that your UIViewController doesn't understand the table view delegate message tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:. I think you should show all the code you have in this controller, including any property declarations in the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a 'count' message to a contacts variable that has been deallocated.  When you assign an object to contacts, be sure it owns it by sending a retain message on it or use the ARC equivalent if you have it enabled.

Comment: @Dolours   these are the values in the array                                                         - (void)viewDidLoad
{
contacts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];

[super viewDidLoad];                                                        
}

Comment: In that case, contacts is being assigned an auto released instance of an array.  Call [contacts retain];

Comment: there's an error: 'retain' is unavailable in automatic reference counting

Comment: Then either declare your contacts as a strong reference or assign using [[NSArray alloc] init.......]

Comment: Try doing this, `contacts = [NSArray alloc]init];` and then assign values to it as you doing earlier.